# Git Tfs not showing all branches

Tags: git-tfs

I've successfully cloned a large repository as follows (I'm showing just parts of it here):

```
# git tfs clone --debug --gitignore=/d/Repos/VisualStudio.gitignore --changeset=51731 --branches=all http://server:8080/tfs/MyCollection $/MyProject/Main MyProject
```

However, I've had a number of errors in the log like

```
  $/MyProject/Releases/21.1
   =>error:GitTfs.Core.GitTfsException: error: Couldn't fetch parent branch
   at GitTfs.Commands.InitBranch.InitBranchSupportingRename(String tfsBranchPath, String gitBranchNameExpected, IList`1 creationBranchData, IGitTfsRemote defaultRemote, IFetchResult& fetchResult)
   at GitTfs.Commands.InitBranch.InitializeBranches(IGitTfsRemote defaultRemote, List`1 childBranchPaths)
```

Now I have:

```
# git tfs branch -r
Found matching Visual Studio version at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional

TFS branch structure:

 $/MyProject/Main -> default [*]
 |
 +- $/MyProject/Releases/20.1 -> Releases/20.1
 |
 +- $/MyProject/Releases/21.1 -> Releases/21.1
 |  |
 |  +- $/MyProject/Releases/21.1.0 -> Releases/21.1.0
```

but the repo only has

```
# git branch
  Releases/21.1.0
* master

# git branch --all
  Releases/21.1.0
* master
  remotes/tfs/Releases/20.1
  remotes/tfs/Releases/21.1
  remotes/tfs/Releases/21.1.0
  remotes/tfs/default
```

The Releases/20.1 and Releases/21.1 local branches are missing. I've run

```
# git tfs branch --init $/MyProject/Releases/20.1
warning : There is already a remote for this tfs branch. Branch ignored!

# git tfs branch --init $/MyProject/Releases/21.1
warning : There is already a remote for this tfs branch. Branch ignored!
```

and

```
# git tfs fetch -d --all
```

The latter gave me some additional changesets:

```
Fetching from TFS remote 'Releases/20.1'...
Commits visited count:1
Commits visited count:1
info: refs/remotes/tfs/Releases/20.1: Getting changesets from 77303 to -1 ...
Setting up a TFS workspace at .git\~w
get [C78089]$/MyProject/Releases/20.1/Source/AP/Source/Business/...
get [C78089]$/MyProject/Releases/20.1/Source/AP/Source/Business/...
get [C78089]$/MyProject/Releases/20.1/Source/AP/Source/Business/...
get [C78089]$/MyProject/Releases/20.1/Source/AP/Source/Business/...
TFS Workspace 'git-tfs-9338d2cd-ca28-4274-8f37-e569ee87b408;HSA' was removed.
C78089 = c813661ce40393a7b01549144dd188d99e4d7d86
GC Countdown: 190
Setting up a TFS workspace at .git\~w
get [C78091]$/MyProject/Releases/20.1/Source/AP/Source/Business/...
get [C78091]$/MyProject/Releases/20.1/Source/AP/Source/Business/...
get [C78091]$/MyProject/Releases/20.1/Source/AP/Source/Business/...
        D       Source/AP/Source/Business/...
TFS Workspace 'git-tfs-ebbe80fc-3c0d-4010-a1b9-fabba018d1e4;HSA' was removed.
C78091 = 940de5f560a08e970ca4e208fcd203d0e0588966
GC Countdown: 189
Cleaning...
Fetching from TFS remote 'Releases/21.1'...
Commits visited count:1
Commits visited count:1
Cleaning...
Fetching from TFS remote 'Releases/21.1.0'...
Commits visited count:1
Commits visited count:1
Cleaning...
```

And I still don't have the Releases/20.1 and Releases/21.1 branches.

Can I fix this somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you been able to fix this in the meanwhile? If so, can you share the solution?

Comment: I can't remember this case specifically. I've had to migrate many TFVC repositories, and I've had to give up on some of the, i.e. just commit the latest snapshot or so.

I've had quite a bit of success by playing with the --changeset parameter, e.g. setting it to the start of a branch or so.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Hope this will help me and others!